# Is it shirk if I say, 'Life always hurts us?'

Tags: shirk

Is it shirk if I say, 'Life hurts us all?'

Please elaborate and explain your answer very clearly. Please elaborate your answers with reference to The Quran and the hadith.

Comment: Thoses people just dowvoting ; &  one person  giving a link it's good  ;i upvoted ur post ; cuz i 'm downvoted  too;

Answer (score 0):

Your question is like , is saying" he helped me"
you know what i'm saying like
[Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFigagHVOtc)
I hope you get it;you should say
Don't attribute the blessings to other things ; by saying this cured me etc...But in your heart keep in mind that it's Allah ;

say rather :"Alhamdulillah this helped me "

So yeah it's okay to say that ; cuz life is a test by Allah anyways to it's like i'm saying "the test is hard "

do you understand ,; not that i'm saying the hardship come from this & this whitout the permission of Allah ;
also the prophet said that the actions are for their intentions

To sum up ; yeah it's okay ,since it's not really what you mean , in your mind you know it's Allah ; especially when you say it when reaction to something in life;  but mention Allah at the end ; like alhamdulillah